# When is it appropriate to use Python's fmean instead of mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

Python 3.8 released `fmean` as part of the `statistics` module, which supplements the existing `mean` function in the same module. As per the docs:

> Convert data to floats and compute the arithmetic mean. This runs faster than the mean() function and it always returns a float.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean

However, the docs don't really discuss any trade-offs. My question is when can I use `fmean` over `mean`, and when should I stick with `mean`?

My specific example is averaging error probabilities, derived from Phred scores, in FASTQ reads. Example:

```py
from statistics import mean

def decode(c):
    return ord(c) - 33

def phred_to_probability(phred_score):
    return 10**(-phred_score/10)

def raw_q_to_probability(q):
    return phred_to_probability(decode(q))

qualities = list("3===RONT{{QKLIFGHEH=::::CAAA@BBA@CCC....00002::;IBCHKJIIHHHEGGGHHGIJGFFFFMKKPILMLGGGGGIMNMEB@CBCDEKNMQQSJJMT{UKOKLLEEDEELGKIJKPEBA==>??@@@HD@?@AH?>?>?IIKIPFFEEFFKIEDDCEHFFHIHIKMLPOHQOH")


mean(raw_q_to_probability(q) for q in qualities)
```

Should I expect any difference in accuracy between the two functions for this application? I note the `fmean` solution has an additional digit reported when executing the above example but is otherwise the same.

Answer (score 1):

From higher up in the `statistics` docs:

> Unless explicitly noted, these functions support int, float, Decimal and Fraction.

`statistics.mean` can take a sequence of Fractions and give you the mean as a Fraction, or take a list of Decimal instances and give you a Decimal. `statistics.fmean` cannot do that.

Also, even when the inputs are already floats, `statistics.mean` may avoid a very slight bit of rounding error, as it does all computations in exact arithmetic until the final conversion to the result type. `statistics.fmean` [uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/statistics.py#L456) [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) to sum the inputs with as much precision as `float` will allow, but the result of `fsum` is still a float, so that's one rounding that `statistics.mean` avoids.

Finally, `statistics.fmean` supports weights. `statistics.mean` does not.